# ASP.net cannot find javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Maybe someone can help me to understand what is the problem, I have been spending hours into google for a solution.

I am using: ASP.NET entity framework

**I have a view with this code:**

```
<button type="button" id="btnGraficoNew">GeneraGrafico</button>
<div id="msgError"></div>
<div id="contenedorGrafico"></div>

@section scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/highcharts")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/paraGrafico")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.date-picker').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true
            }).next().on(ace.click_event, function () {
                $(this).prev().focus();
            });
            $("#btnGraficoNew").click("click", function () {
                alert("dentro de a");
                AlertaMensaje("hola mundo");
                ListaPubli(1, 1, 1);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

When I run the program the browser alert me with: "**Uncaught ReferenceError: AlertaMensaje is not defined**" but If I check into the page code the call exist.

[image: pageGrafico.js source code access]

Into google dev tools this is what I can see

[image: google dev tools]

1. reference to paraGrafico.js file.
2. cannot find a function that is inside of paraGrafico.js
3. javascript file doesn't appear into content.

Any idea?

Comment: seems like your pages is located in `/GServices/Teficiancio`, and it will look for the javascript file in `/GServices/Teficiancio/Content/js/paraGrafico.js`. Try after chaging the src inside script tag to `../../Content/js/paraGrafico.js`

Comment: @AlwaysaLearner the result is the same. I supposed it is something relative to scope, but I cannot understand how to solve. If I locate the code directly to view Teficiencia the program run without problem. How I bundle is:   `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/highcharts").Include(
                      "~/Content/js/highcharts.js",
                      "~/Content/js/exporting.js"));

 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/paraGrafico").Include(
                      "~/Content/js/paraGrafico.js"));`  if you see I use the same way for **paraGrafico.js** and for **highchart.js**.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that inside "paraGrafico.js" there was a javascript code error.

```
url: "@Url.Action("method", "controller")",

change to

url: '@Url.Action("method", "controller")',
```

After to solve it the browser call the function without problem.